# Разная высота колонок в bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Верстаю простенький шаблон из макета без модульной сетки. Решил, что проще будет подогнать это дело под bootstrap.
Реально-ли сверстать макет со скрина с помощью модульной сетки бутстрапа? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

> Реально-ли сверстать макет со скрина с помощью модульной сетки бутстрапа?

Да, с помощью Bootstrap можно сделать все тоже, что и стандартными средствами css, html и javascript, только гораздо быстрее.

Различная высота колонок в данном случае регулируется отступами.

Чтобы было легче ориентироваться, вбейте в поисковике "psd grid bootstrap" и скачайте сетку для Photoshop. Затем просто перенесите свой макет. Направляющие укажут ширину столбцов и отступы.

Если шаблон в 12 колонок вас не устраивает, то на сайте Bootstrap можно кастомизировать и скачать bootstrap-grid под то количество колонок (и их ширину), которое подходит вам.

Comment: Можно немного поподробнее про отступы?

Comment: @PavelMoleskin Кастомная сетка:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/#grid-system
Выбираете нужные вам величины (кол-во колонок и ширину отступов между ними) и скачиваете. Вверху страницы можно оставить отмеченным только пункт Grid system, если Вам нужна только сетка.